# Kubernetes external routing to services

Tags: kubernetes

I just setup kubernetes using minikube on my local mac.

Created a service with type NodePort and able to access my service outside the cluster using the url `<Cluster_IP>:<NodePort>`.

Enabled ingress on my minikube and able to route calls from outside the cluster to the service in the cluster.

Going to setup Kubernetes cluster on our private cloud. We are not using AWS/Google/Azure cloud. It is our own cloud with Linux VM's.

Using netscalar for creating VIP's and routing requests to applications deployed in Linux VM's.

Do i need to still continue creating VIP for my application and routes calls to ingress from VIP or to the NodePort?

Is there any other better approach without creating a VIP in netscalar?

Answer (score 1):

It is by far the best approach to use your infrastructure potential to the fullest. If you have a network loadbalancer where you can configure VIP and point it to your nodes (NodePort) then for http(s) services I would strongly advise doing just that.

For convenience I would configure one IP and point it to the NodePort service of your clusters ingress controller and then use Ingress to expose your services to the outside world.

Comment: I just came across external dns. https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/automatic-dns-kubernetes-ingresses-externaldns/